# Run Python Script with variable in arguments

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, shell

I have a python command that runs as follows:

```
python script.py -file 1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.NUMBER --out GTEx_Cortex.chrNUMBER
```

I would like to replace the `NUMBER` variable with the numbers 1:20. So if I replace `NUMBER` with `1` it would look like this:

```
python script.py -file 1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.1 --out GTEx_Cortex.chr1
```

and this on the second iteration (if I replace it with 2):

```
python script.py -file 1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.2 --out GTEx_Cortex.chr2
```

But I don't want to keep manually changing `NUMBER` 20 times. I want to automate the entire thing.

How can I do this in the command prompt? Should this be done in VIM or is there another way in python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in `seq 1 20`;do python script.py -file 1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.${i} --annot GTEx_Cortex_chr1.annot.gz --out GTEx_Cortex.chr${i};done
```

Comment: `1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.${i}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this frequently you could also write a bash script.

Create a file `run_stuff` that loops through commands. It could be analogous to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$1
i=1
while (( i <= n )); do
    python prog${i}.py
    (( i = i + 1 ))
done
```

The above script runs `prog1.py`, then `prog2.py`, and so on. For your code, just replace the 5th line with the analogous line you want.

Then in the terminal you would do:

```
chmod u+x run_stuff
./run_stuff 20
```

The `chmod` command just changes the permissions of the file so you can execute it.

Comment: Silly question, what is in prog1.py, for example? Would it be the command I stated in the question?

Comment: No, the idea was just to show how to call commands with arguments that iterate. Substituting the line `python prog${i}.py` with `python script.py -file 1000G_EUR_Phase3_plink/1000G.${i} --annot GTEx_Cortex_chr1.annot.gz --out GTEx_Cortex.chr${i}` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I just answered the question with the `python prog${i}.py` part since it is easily reproducible by anyone with python (including me so I can actually make sure it works :) ).